# Display Views Result Summary in Twig Template

Tags: views, theming, 8

I have views with exposed filter and display exposed filter as a block. I need something like views result summary on my twig template. How am I supposed to achieve this in Drupal way.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you mean views results count. If that is what you are looking for then you get it by 
 {{ view.total_rows }}

Comment: thanks for reply. Yes I'm trying to show result count, but I want it show on my exposed block before it start some queries. It's like some guide to user about total data before they click the submit button.

I already use{{ view.total_rows }} but it show nothing.